# Getting MalformedJsonException using Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm creating an app that gets data from my server however I'm getting the following exception...

```
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

The JSON I'm retrieving is from this URL http://soulappvm.cloudapp.net/SAService/Service.svc/userlist

The JSON seems to be correctly formatted so I'm unsure why I'm getting this error.

JSON

```
[{
    "Name": "Daniel1user",
    "Password": "40d5e24c5c906103a980ec7c69c100c5",
    "Address": "123 st"
}, {
    "Name": "Daniel2user",
    "Password": "90a1587cbe37d4a2a128ce758f338587",
    "Address": "1234 st"
}, {
    "Name": "Daniel3user",
    "Password": "f97c27c65d3af0d18657cbae16f9d57e",
    "Address": "ccc"
}, {
    "Name": "user1user",
    "Password": "def907bec025cd03bf738c3612bd7926",
    "Address": "ds"
}, {
    "Name": "user2user",
    "Password": "0fa04e1c4a5720195b106df9e746a72b",
    "Address": "ff"
}]
```

Is there a way to print the response I'm actually recieving to the logcat to see what is going wrong?

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://soulappvm.cloudapp.net/SAService/Service.svc/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        MyApiEndpointInterface apiService = retrofit.create(MyApiEndpointInterface.class);
        Call<List<User>> call = apiService.getUsers();
                call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
                    @Override

                    public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
                        int statusCode = response.code();
                        System.out.println("response:  " + statusCode);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
                        System.out.println("It failed:  " + t);
                    }
                });
```

My interface

```
public interface MyApiEndpointInterface {
    @GET("userlist")
    Call<List<User>> getUsers();
}
```

Comment: You could create a custom Gson deserializer to manually check and deserialize the JSON you receive: https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html

Comment: @Mauin would you be able to give me an example of how I could do this?

Comment: Here is a test that creates a custom deserializer for the User object. After creating the Gson instance you should use that one with the registered deserializer to initialize Retrofit. http://pastebin.com/bQJywq0M

Comment: @Mauin So create a new class called UserJsonTest, paste your code into that class then in my main activity create a Gson instance and add it to GsonConverterFactory.create()?

Comment: No. That is just a Test Class. Create the Deserializer class in your project, and create a Gson instance like shown in the Test example and pass that along in the `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))`

Comment: @Mauin I found my issue, If you look at the URL link above and view source you will see that what actually is being return is JSON wrapped in Xml. How do I get around this?

Comment: @M0rty Ask backend guys to make up their mind, either they going to use XML or JSON.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski This is actually my fault, I have created the backend but still learning. How would I make it return just JSON? I can post more code

Comment: @M0rty Result data serialize it using anything that can produce JSON.

Answer (score 0):

`public class TestApi {`

```
private final TaskTest mTask;
public static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
public TestApi(){
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
mTask = restAdapter.create(TaskTest.class);
}

public interface TaskTest{
    @GET(/test)
    void testResponse(Callback<List<test>> cb);
}
public void fetchTest(Callback<List<test>> cb){
    mTask.testResponse(cb);
}
}
```

And the call should be something like this

```
mTestApi.fetchTest(new Callback<List<test>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<test> tests, Response response) {

        }
        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
```